# Bash - Process metastat data by each Mirror

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a bunch of output from the following command:

```
 metastat |egrep 'Submirror|State|d' |egrep -v 'Read|Write|c|Reloc'
```

The output looks as follows:

```
d15: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d16
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d17
      State: Okay
d16: Submirror of d15
    State: Okay
d17: Submirror of d15
    State: Okay
d25: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d26
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d27
      State: Okay
d26: Submirror of d25
    State: Okay
d27: Submirror of d25
    State: Okay
```

etc ..

I would like to put each mirror set into an Array.

for example:

```
echo ${array[0]}
d15: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d16
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d17
      State: Okay
d16: Submirror of d15
    State: Okay
d17: Submirror of d15
    State: Okay

echo ${array[1]}
d25: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d26
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d27
      State: Okay
d26: Submirror of d25
    State: Okay
d27: Submirror of d25
    State: Okay
```

What is the best soloution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure `bash` solution:

```
declare -a MIRROR_ARR
COUNT=-1
IFS=''
while read -r line 
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ Mirror ]]; then
        COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
        MIRROR_ARR[$COUNT]=$line
    else
        MIRROR_ARR[$COUNT]=$(printf '%s\n%s' "${MIRROR_ARR[$COUNT]}" "$line")
    fi
done < <(metastat |egrep 'Submirror|State|d' |egrep -v 'Read|Write|c|Reloc')

echo "${MIRROR_ARR[0]}"
echo "----"
echo "${MIRROR_ARR[1]}"
```

Comment: Wow. Very intelligent scripting. You Sir, are a gentleman and a saint.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`csplit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html) (POSIX) in this way:

```
csplit -z your_file /Mirror/ {*}
```

Here, `z` is the short of `--elide-empty-files` and `{*}` is to repeat the previous pattern as many times as possible.

---

If the number of lines is fixed (**9** in your case) you can do it with [`split`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split):

```
split -l9 your_file
```

---

In both cases, if you want to save the content of each file in an array, you can do it in this way:

```
i=0 IFS=
for mirror in <prefix>*; do array[((i++))]=$(cat $mirror); done
```

Replacing `<prefix>` with the prefix you choose or the default.

---

#### Example with `csplit`

```
$ cat your_file
d15: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d16
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d17
      State: Okay
d16: Submirror of d15
    State: Okay
d17: Submirror of d15
    State: Okay
d25: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d26
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d27
      State: Okay
d26: Submirror of d25
    State: Okay
d27: Submirror of d25
    State: Okay

$ csplit -z your_file /Mirror/ {*}
166
166

$ ls -1
xx00
xx01
your_file

$ i=0 IFS=
$ for mirror in xx*; do array[((i++))]=$(cat $mirror); done

$ echo ${array[0]}
d15: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d16
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d17
      State: Okay
d16: Submirror of d15
    State: Okay
d17: Submirror of d15
    State: Okay

$ echo ${array[1]}
d25: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d26
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d27
      State: Okay
d26: Submirror of d25
    State: Okay
d27: Submirror of d25
    State: Okay
```